# Two fonts in the same input

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm trying to style a search input so that it has a placeholder that includes the FontAwesome magnifying glass `fa-search [&#xf002;]`. The words "Search User" need to be in a Gotham Light font at the same time the magnifying glass is in the FontAwesome font.

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like now. All that needs to be corrected is to change the serif font to the Gotham Light font I have specified on the rest of the page.

[image: search user input]

This is the code that produces that result:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="fa fa-search input-search-user" placeholder="&#xf002; Search User">
</div>
```

Here is the code that makes the "Search User" text appear in the correct Gotham Light font, but which also breaks the FontAwesome magnifying glass.

```
<div>
    <input type="text" class="input-search-user" placeholder="&#xf002; Search User">
</div>
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

So, as you can see, it's "either/or" with using FontAwesome with another font in the same input. I've been told that I should make the div simulate the input box and just style the div, but I'm having a hard time sleuthing out how to do that.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: I dont belive this is possible. I suggest you just find a nice font!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add a span and move it over the text field and indent the placeholder text, like the following example:

HTML:

```
<div class="search">
  <span class="fa fa-search"></span>
 <input placeholder="Search user">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.search {
  position: relative;
  color: #aaa;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.search input {
  width: 250px;
  height: 32px;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.search input { 
  text-indent: 32px;
}

.search .fa-search { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

http://codepen.io/williamjamesclark/pen/WrKJEV

Comment: You could also add `.search input:focus ~ span {  display: none; }` and `.search input:focus { text-indent: 10px; }` to make it behave a bit more like a placeholder while typing. Good answer!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this with an input field only. 
But you could try this:

```
<div class="input">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Search User" />
   <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</div>
```

And do it like this:

```
.input{
   position: relative;
}
.input input{
   font-family: FONTHERE;
}
.input i{
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 5px; //Just guessing
   transform: translate(-50%,-50%); //centerize it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but it's possible to simply show a Font Awesome icon and text of another font in the same input. The font stack in CSS starts with Font Awesome, then the other font after it.

OP's placeholder attribute in HTML is fine:

```
 <input type="text" "placeholder="&#xf002; Search User">
```

Here's the CSS for the input:

```
font-family: 'Font Awesome', 'someWebFont', sans-serif;
```

Here it is in the wild: https://autocamp.com/contact/

[image: email text input with Font Awesome and another font]